# Como mostrar valor de um atributo no content: de um pseudo-elemento?

Tags: html, css, css3

Eu quero mostrar o valor de um atributo como texto.

```html
<div title="12:56pm">
    <span data-measureme="1">
        <span>hi</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Exemplo que não funciona [no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLWVm/).

Algo como

```css
div > span:before {
    content: parent.title;
}
```

É possível fazer isso com CSS? Como/por quê?

Sobre compatibilidade de navegadores, eu preciso apenas que rode na última versão do Chrome e Firefox. Mas se houver uma solução que funcione em qualquer browser seria legal.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo dos Downvote's, coloquei +1 porque acredito que essa questão não está ruim.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente acho a pergunta boa e simples e que serve para responder outras perguntas que estavam mais confusas, editei o titulo, porque creio que talvez os downvotes tenham sido pela dificuldade de entender e também já deixo um +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSS *ainda* não tem uma maneira para acessar atributos de um elemento pai. Entretanto é possível obter um atributo através de `attr()`, [documentado aqui em inglês](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr).

```
content: attr(title);
```

Desta forma a única maneira é adaptar o seletor para pegar o elemento que contém a propriedade.

```
div:before {
    content: attr(title);
}
```

Veja o [exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLWVm/1/).

Comment: Não sei por que você havia recebido down vote. Respondeu que não há como e deu um exemplo mais próximo do que foi perguntado.

Comment: Não vejo uma aplicação real pra isso .-.

Comment: @WillianRibeiro eu já usei, porque alguns elementos que aplico com um controle de `data-` em uma especie de "web component", mas para navegadores sem suporte a tal tecnologia (web component). Eu acho que a pergunta é bem simples, mas mesmo assim serve para cobrir todos casos de problemas similares (encontrei 3 perguntas novas com problemas que isso resolveria), espero que todos aqui concordem.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez se você colocar um `value` ou um `placeholde`r.
A sua pergunta ficou confusa.